# Received a written job offer but no contract and no start date

Tags: job-search, job-offer, follow-up

I went for an interview last week at a big organisation which went well. The next day I got a call from HR stating they would like to offer me the position. I was so happy, because I've been out of work for some time and I really wanted the role.

On the call they asked me if I was happy with the salary, and asked about the start date which will be confirmed after the pre employment checks as it depended on how long it would take.. They sent me a written offer email with the role, salary, contract type and start date to be confirmed. She then said she will raise the contract, but it's been almost a week and haven't heard anything back.

She did said say she was out of office for a few days...  However, I'm starting to get a bit worried about this. I just wanted to know if it usually takes this long to receive the job contract? Or would there be something else wrong? I know they are probably busy with work but surely it won't take long to send a contract/start date?

I don't know! I am relatively new to the work force as a graduate so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: What country? Please add a country tag. In USA it's not common for salaried workers to have contracts separate from offer letters. It's also common to leave the start date negotiable. They're not playing games with you, just doing their process.

Comment: In my experience (UK) start dates are often dependent on notice periods. I wouldn't normally hand in my notice until the contract arrives, and so any conversation about start dates would include a caveat along the lines of [Contract arrival/signing date + notice period = start date] with the meaning that if they want me to start in 5 weeks time, with a 4 week notice period, then they need to get that contact to me within 1 week. (Although I have worked smaller notice periods upon negotiation - *I once worked a 2 day notice period instead of a month*)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> On the call they asked me if I was happy with the salary, and asked about **the start date which will be confirmed after the pre employment checks** as it depended on how long it would take..

I would give it more time. She already stated that the date will be established once the checks are done.

You say it's been less than a week since the call, and that she even was out of office for some days (these two facts show that little time has passed). This means that the pre-employment checks are not done yet...

Here in The Workplace, it is usually suggested that you should wait [*at least* a week](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/6021/73791) before considering writing or following up for a position, and in this case not even a week has passed.

I know you may be anxious or excited :) but I wouldn't worry about this yet.

Still, it would be wise to keep your options open, and continue looking/interviewing for other positions, just in case this offer fails.